# How to hide e-mail signature in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

I'd like to know if there is a way to auto-hide e-mail signatures in Thunderbird (setting or extension). Ideally, it should only show a line with some text like "Click here to display signature".

It's pretty annoying when in an e-mail thread some people write 2-3 lines of content and have 15 line signatures.

Comment: I don’t think this is possible, because signatures are basically part of the regular message body. You could only approach this problem heuristically.

Comment: Imho, this problem has to addressed not by hiding signatures when reading email, but by educating people and teaching them to use email client properly. Most modern email clients have an option to include signature only once within the email thread and to omit it in all replies. (I know this does not help to resolve your problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2.8.1 version of the [Thunderbird Conversations](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/thunderbird/addon/gmail-conversation-view/) extension [claims to have](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/thunderbird/addon/gmail-conversation-view/versions/) the ability to collapse signatures by default.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the add-on
[Element Hiding Helper for Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/elemhidehelper/?src=search).
It should work as long as the signature is a separate block in the message.
If this is not the case, I don't think there is an easy solution.

> Element Hiding Helper is a companion extension for Adblock Plus meant
>   to make creating element hiding rules easier.
>
> You simply select the element you want to be hidden and then choose
>   which attributes of this element should be taken into account when
>   hiding it in future. The element hiding rule is generated and added
>   automatically.
>
> This add-on requires the following add-ons to work properly: [Adblock
>   Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/adblock-plus/?src=dp-dl-dependencies).

[image]